# Apache config syntax failing in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having problems deploying in Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat).

When I deploy my WAR, an Apache config syntax check is done:

`/usr/sbin/apachectl -t -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

But it fails because that `httpd.conf` doesn't define modules needed:

```
Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
Invalid command 'SetEnvIf', perhaps misspelled or defined...
```

That modules, in this case, `setenvif_module`is defined in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`that is my httpd config file.

I don't know where `/var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`comes from.

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: You may wish to see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=759487. I am working the same issue with AWS. I seem to have found an issue with their scripts when you rebuild the environment. A quick fix is probably to include your own httpd.conf file which is a copy of theirs, but add in the setenvif.so module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my investigation, this seems only related to an initial instance install/build using Elastic Beanstalk. The ssl.conf file in question actually comes from the initial Apache install and is not part of the Elastic Beanstalk configuration.

The issue is happening because AWS no longer installs mod_setenvif.so as a module in httpd.conf and therefore this error is being thrown.

In order to remove this ongoing issue from my builds and due to the fact that I already customize my Apache configuration, I copied a working AWS httpd.conf file from another instance and added the mod_setenvif.so module to it. Using the directions at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-proxy-apache, Elastic Beanstalk configuration scripts use the new httpd.conf file and the error is no longer thrown.

I consider this a workaround answer since the main scripts is controlled by AWS. It my be a defect in the script or it may not. Regardless, I just wanted to find a solution quickly.

Comment: You are right, I spent 5 hours with an AWS support guy and finally we resolved the issue using my own httpd.conf in .ebextensions. He discouraged using BeansTalk for this kind of mess.

Comment: So the .so (mod_setenvif.so) is in `/etc/httpd/modules` but not installed? This is very confusing!